# How do I convert the jquery Isotope select box filter code to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am trying to convert this jQuery select box filter code in Isotope to pure javascript because the jquery version doesn't work on our site. Here is the jQuery code

```
$('#filters').on( 'change', function() {
// get filter value from option value
var filterValue = this.value;
// use filterFn if matches value
filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
$container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

Here is my converted javascript:

```
//Filter on change event
function filtersElem(){
var filtersElem = document.getElementById("filters");
if(filtersElem[filtersElem.selectedIndex].value==filterValue {
// use matching filter function
filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
iso.arrange({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

What am I missing?  It is not working.  I just need to convert the above jQuery back to vanilla javascript. I am new to pure javascript.

Thanks for your help!

here is a jsfiddle that shows the problem http://jsfiddle.net/EFRR3/11/

Comment: -1 overused joke ^ :D

Comment: filters.onchange=function(){  iso.arrange({ filter: filterFns[filters.value]||filters.value });}

Comment: thanks for your help...don't I have to define the filters.value too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to Nico pointing me in the right direction...

this is the final translation of the code from jQuery to javascript

this jquery:

```
$('#filters').on( 'change', function() {
// get filter value from option value
var filterValue = this.value;
// use filterFn if matches value
filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
$container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

is this in javscript

```
document.getElementById('filters');
filters.onchange = function () {

var filterValue = this.value;
//use filterFn if matches value
filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
iso.arrange({ filter: filterValue});
 }
```

you also have to make sure you are calling "value=" in the html instead of "data-filter="  for example

```
<option value="*">Show All 22 Recipe Collections</option>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write your solution (y)

Answer (score 1):

Due to some comments, I would provide some details about my answer.

Here is your original code:

```
$('#filters').on( 'change', function() {
  // get filter value from option value
  var filterValue = this.value;
  // use filterFn if matches value
  filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
  $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

In code you provide, we can easily replace:

```
$('#filters').on( 'change', callback);
```

by

```
document.getElementById('filters').onChange = callback;
```

We still have to rewrite the callback.

```
var callback = function() {

  // You declare filterValue and store the current select value inside
  var filterValue = this.value;

  // And then, you erase it if a function is found, in something I imagine defined as an array.
  filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;

  // Then, process to your stuff
  $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
```

}

You've to admit you just want to use the filter method if defined, otherwise, the selected value.

You can simplify like this:

```
var callback = function() {
  $container.isotope({ filter: filterFns[ this.value ] || this.value });
}
```

Comment: When I use jQuery on our site it conflicts so I converted the whole Isotope script to javascript with buttons and that works wine, but for mobile I need a drop down select box because of space contraints

Comment: Done ;) To avoid conflict, user3738811, you can use isolated scope.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the whole part where you actually bind a callback to the element's `change` event.

Comment: You haven't translated this part: `...on( 'change', function() {`